# Build array of object on onChange event with setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Failed to build a form with dynamic property. I can normalize the form later but try to avoid doing another extra function but because I can do it within the onChange method.

//desire output

```
formData: {
  name: 'alice',
  addresses: [{
    address_id: 1, address: 'UK'
  }, {
    address_id: 2, address: 'USA'
  }]
}
```

I'm stucked.

https://codesandbox.io/s/l528yw35x9

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: @AlexanderElgin I want to produce *desire output with 2 way binding

Comment: [**check this working code**](https://codesandbox.io/s/rrjwmlky7o), better to store the addresses also in object, then change the format before hitting the api, it will be easy to manage the data with objects.

Comment: @MayankShukla ur link doesn't work

Comment: @GlobinHughes [check this one](https://codesandbox.io/s/6yn83w848r).

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to your problem is by initializing the addresses array in your form data like this

```
this.state = {
  formData: {addresses:[
    {
      address_id: 1, address: 'UK'
    }, {
      address_id: 2, address: 'USA'
    }
  ]}
}
```

now in your **onChange** method  you can map the elements of addresses like this

```
else{
  //{address_id: inputId, address: value}
  this.setState({
    formData: {
      ...this.state.formData, addresses:
        this.state.formData.addresses.map(e=>{
        return e.address_id == inputId ? 
          { address_id: inputId,address:value} : e
        }),

      }
  })
}
```

look at the complete example below 
https://codesandbox.io/s/0omj21nrpv